# Yosys: Getting Gates /Transistor count

Tags: yosys

I am new to Yosys and synthesis but what I want to achieve is to get the number of gates and transistors after the design unit has undergone synthesis. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat` for gate count statistics, `stat -lib` for area statistics for a liberty file, or `stat -tech cmos` for transistor count using CMOS-type gates.